# How to read from file in c++ and insert data from file into vector thats is type of an class?

Tags: c++

Like the title says I need to insert data from file into vector that is a type of class I created.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Film.h"
#include "Comedy.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
Comedy k;
Film f;

int main() {
    vector <Comedy> comedy;
   

    ifstream Comedies("Comedy.txt", ios::in);
    int number = 0;
    string line;
    while (getline(Comedies, line)) {
        br++;
        komedija.push_back(line); // this is where I get the error
    }
```

This is Comedy class:

```
#pragma once
#include "Film.h"
#include "Actor.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

enum Type2 {black = 1, romantic, child};

class Comedy :
    public Film
{
private:
    vector<Actor>actors;
    Type2 typeComedy;
public:
    void setActors();
    vector<Actors>& getActors();
    void setType();
    Type2 getType();
    void insert();
};
```

Anyone know what is the issue, I assume it is because the `line` variable is a type of string, and I am trying to insert into a vector that is not type of string, how do I then insert data from file into a vector that is not string?

This is a Film class:

```
#pragma once
class Film
{
private:
    char name[25];
    int timeOfDuration;
    char startMovieTime[7];
public:
    Film();
    void setName();
    char* getName();
    void setTimeOfDuration();
    int getTimeOfDuratiion();
    void setStartMovieTime();
    char* getStartMovieTime();
    ~Film() {};
};
```

Comment: `komedija.push_back(line);` should produce an error because the variable is declared as `vector <Comedy> comedy;` - Btw, should `Comedy` really be a class of its own? It feels more like it could be a category member in `Film`

Comment: I wrote a code in Bosnian, but for this question I translated the code from Bosnian into English, so I forgot to change komedija.push_back(linija) into comedy.push_back(line)

Comment: @TedLyngmo - but `comedy.push_back(line);` will also produce an error: pushing string into  vector of Comedy.

Comment: @Eugene Yes. If `Film` has a constructor taking a `std::string` I suggest using `.emplace_back(line);` instead - and do `using Film::Film;` in `Comedy`

Comment: @TedLyngmo where should I insert using Film::Film; in Comedy?

Comment: You need to write code that parses the line into a `Comedy`. How to do this depends on the exact text format.

Comment: @ahmedskulj10 I made it into an answer to show it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Film` has a constructor that takes a `std::string`, I suggest adding it to the derived classes:

Example with `Comedy`:

```
class Comedy : public Film {
public:
    using Film::Film; // add the `Film` constructor(s)
    // ...
};
```

Then adding a new `Comedy` can be done using [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```
komedija.emplace_back(line);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/coWxj3c3E)

If you for some reason want to store the film name in a `char[]`, you can still use a constructor that accepts a `std::string` and stores it in your `char[]`.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::copy_n, std::min

class Film {
private:
    char name[25];

public:
    Film() : name{} {} // initialize name

    // added constructor:
    Film(const std::string& Name) : Film() {
        std::copy_n(Name.c_str(), std::min(sizeof name - 1, Name.size()), name);
    }
};
```

Note: Unless `Comedy` has some special member variables/functions I suggest adding a `category` member to `Film` instead of inheriting from `Film`.

Comment: My class Film has a char variables, and it doesn't have std::string variables. So how to do this then when I have char variables?

Comment: @ahmedskulj10 I would change those to `std::string` variables immediately.

Comment: I agree, but I want to do them this way so I can practice. If you would show me how, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @ahmedskulj10 Sure - please add the current definition of `Film` to the question and I'll add that as an option

Comment: I have edited the question, and added the Film class.

Comment: @ahmedskulj10 Great - I added a possible fix

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way is to use the iterator constructor of vector

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream       comedyFile("Comedy.txt")
    std::vector<Comedy> comedy(std::istream_iterator<Comedy>(comedyFile),
                               std::istream_iterator<Comedy>{});

}
```

This assumes that the `Comedy` has an `operator>>` defined that will read from a stream into a default constructed `Comedy` object.

```
class Comedy
{
    public:
        Comedy(){}  // creates a default object.
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Comedy& obj) {
            obj.load(stream);
            return stream;
        }
    private:
        void load(std::istream& stream) {
            // read from the stream into your object.
        }
};
```

---

Sometimes creating a default object is not practical or nice. In this case you can create a "Reader" object that reads data and allows construction of the object.

```
  int main()
{
    std::ifstream       comedyFile("Comedy.txt")
    std::vector<Comedy> comedy(std::istream_iterator<ComedyReader>(comedyFile),
                               std::istream_iterator<ComedyReader>{});

}
```

This assumes that the `ComedyReader` has an `operator>>` defined that will read from a stream. You can then store the data from the file in a way that is useful and then construct the object when it is pushed into the vector (as this will cause a cast you just need to be able to cast the object into a Comedy).

```
class ComedyReader
{
    std::string  dataForComedy;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, ComedyReader& reader) {
        std::getline(stream, dataForComedy);
        return stream;
    }
    // Now we need to be able to create a Comedy from a string.
    operator Comedy() const {
        return Comedy(std::move(dataForComedy));
    }
};

class Comedy
{
    public:
        Comedy(std::string data) {
            // read from the string into your object.
        }
};
```

---

When moving objects around it is always nice to provide move constructors (though sometimes copy constructors will suffice).

```
class Comedy
{
    public:
        // Move Operators
        Comedy(Comedy&& src)            noexcept;
        Comedy& operator=(Comedy&& src) noexcept;

        // Copy Operators
        Comedy(Comedy const& src);
        Comedy& operator=(Comedy const& src);
};
```